# "Permission denied, please try again", When Trying to Use Visual Studio Code to Connect to Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, digital-ocean, droplet

I have a basic droplet set up that is password protected, have the Remote - SSH extension of VScode installed, and the config file should be right.

```
    # Read more about SSH config files: https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config
Host root
    HostName 24.199.86.101
    User root
```

But I still get this response after putting in my password.

[image: snapshot of VScode password prompt for droplet server connection]

```
[05:41:51.305] Log Level: 2
[05:41:51.316] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+root", attempt 1
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {}
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[05:41:51.317] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[05:41:51.318] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[05:41:51.322] VS Code version: 1.77.3
[05:41:51.322] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.100.0
[05:41:51.322] win32 x64
[05:41:51.324] SSH Resolver called for host: root
[05:41:51.324] Setting up SSH remote "root"
[05:41:51.328] Using commit id "704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710" and quality "stable" for server
[05:41:51.333] Install and start server if needed
[05:41:53.632] Checking ssh with "C:\Python311\Scripts\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.634] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python311\Scripts\ssh.exe ENOENT
[05:41:53.635] Checking ssh with "C:\Python311\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.636] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\Python311\ssh.exe ENOENT
[05:41:53.636] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.637] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh.exe ENOENT
[05:41:53.638] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.642] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\ssh.exe ENOENT
[05:41:53.642] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.643] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\ssh.exe ENOENT
[05:41:53.643] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.645] Got error from ssh: spawn C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ssh.exe ENOENT
[05:41:53.645] Checking ssh with "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -V"
[05:41:53.682] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

[05:41:53.687] Remote command length: 6211/8192 characters
[05:41:53.687] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 52821 root powershell
[05:41:53.690] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[05:41:54.097] > root@24.199.86.101's password:]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[05:41:54.097] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[05:41:54.098] Showing password prompt
[05:42:06.795] Got password response
[05:42:06.796] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********************"
[05:42:06.821] > 
[05:42:09.250] > Permission denied, please try again.
> root@24.199.86.101's password: 
[05:42:09.251] Showing password prompt
[05:42:57.896] Got password response
[05:42:57.897] "install" wrote data to terminal: "********************"
[05:42:57.897] > root@24.199.86.101's password:
> Permission denied, please try again.
> root@24.199.86.101's password:
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[05:42:57.897] Showing password prompt
[05:43:20.165] Password dialog canceled
[05:43:20.166] "install" terminal command canceled
[05:43:20.166] > root@24.199.86.101's password:
> Permission denied, please try again.
> root@24.199.86.101's password:
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[05:43:20.167] Resolver error: Error: Connecting was canceled
    at m.Canceled (c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:584341)
    at c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:680869
[05:43:20.168] Showing password prompt
[05:43:20.174] ------




[05:43:21.802] Password dialog canceled
[05:43:21.802] "install" terminal command canceled
[05:43:21.802] > root@24.199.86.101's password:
> Permission denied, please try again.
> root@24.199.86.101's password:
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
[05:43:21.803] Showing password prompt
```

I've double-checked that my password is right. I tried typing it in and using copy and paste to no change in result.

Comment: There are a few things that could cause this. Are you able to connect to this server as root with a password using the command-line ssh utility?

Comment: I can't, for some reason.

When I try to enter "ssh root@24.199.86.101" I get a "Permission denied, please try again." response.

I am working at a high school at the moment and using their wifi. So maybe that is it?

@Kenster

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lskn1Xr-q8E

I just followed this tutorial with 2 adjustments

1. Make sure to manually transfer all of the files your bot needs after he's done walking you through installations via the command line or it won't run.
2. Upgrade Node to its latest version.

Comment: Glad you found the answer! If possible, you should [edit] your answer to include the most important details from the link provided in the answer itself. This will help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working for whatever reason.